# How could I add nodes to a list by using strcmp on the names in the struct?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, nodes, nodelist

I am working on a nodelist where I can do things like add to the front or end and remove from the front or end but I also want to be able to make an order list as well. So I have a method/function in which I named add_inorder..

So far this is what I have

```
// the struct:
typedef struct node
{
  int id;
  char* name;
  struct node* next;
} node;

void add_inorder(node** head, node* new_node) {
  node* previous = *head;

  if (!*head) {
    *head = new_node;
  }

  else if (strcmp((*head)->name, new_node->name) > 0) {
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
  }

  else {
    node* it = (*head)->next;
    while (it) {
      if (strcmp(it->name, new_node->name) > 0) {
        new_node->next = it;
        previous->next = new_node;
        break;
      }

      previous = it;
      it = it->next;
      if (previous->next == NULL) {
        previous->next = new_node;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

SCREEN DUMP:

```
General stuff ... 
--------------------------------------------------
Memory used to date : 0
node size : 24
List length now is : 0
Memory used to date : 0
Print List : 

--------------------------------------------------

Add Inorder / Remove Inorder ... 
--------------------------------------------------
Adding node : {0, Jill}
List length now is : 1
Memory used to date : 29
Print List : 
{0, Jill}

Adding node : {1, Jane}
List length now is : 2
Memory used to date : 58
Print List : 
{1, Jane}
{0, Jill}

Adding node : {2, Jeff}
List length now is : 3
Memory used to date : 87
Print List : 
{1, Jane}
{2, Jeff}
{0, Jill}

Adding node : {3, Jz}
List length now is : 4
Memory used to date : 114
Print List : 
{1, Jane}
{2, Jeff}
{0, Jill}
{3, Jz}
```

Edited: question now is I think my code is a bit buggy it worked when I put in some breaks, how would you suggest I fix it?

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edit the original code block or add one that shows the current state.

Comment: Hey, I fixed it but I had to throw in some breaks. Before it was infinitely looping and I am not sure why. But the changes I made are very drastic.

Comment: "So far this is what I have" --> post the definition of `node`, and sample code that shows "I can get an insert done".

Comment: Provide a compile-able and run-able example of the problem as it currently stands.  Then we can help you.

Comment: I posted the screen dump. The only thing that I need is to figure out how to get this same output but without the use of the breaks.

Comment: I get why i needed to put the breaks but I wish there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to call `add_inorder()` recursively, such that you are going to reuse your `if()` and `else if()` branches for each node in the list.

If these checks fail, then retry with next node:

```
else
{
    add_inorder(&previous->next, new_node);
}
```

On the downside it is using more stack memory depending on the size of a list.